# Protractor continuing despite beforeEach function erroring and not calling done

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

In my protractor tests, I have several beforeEach functions. If one of them contains an error (that actually gets printed out after all my tests have ran), protractor just continues onto the next beforeEach, which just wastes a ton of time since then it has to execute potentially correct code before finally exiting and informing me of the error that happened almost immediately. An example:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  // I forget to actually call the function thus testDocument is a function not a document
  this.testDocument = someMongoDocumentConsutrctor;
  // This throws an error since testDocument is mistakenly not a document and has no save
  // This is where the protractor tests should exit immediately
  // And since .save is undefined there is no way this code calls done
  this.testDocument.save(done);
});

it('should show show the welcome overlay', function() {
  // This code actually throws an error while the test is running
  // before protractor logs anything else including the error that must've already occurred
  expect(overlay.welcomeMessage.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
})
```

The error message thrown during the test execution is:

```
(node:34486) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, tutorial-overlay)
```

The beginning of the overall output of protractor is (with describe block names redacted):

```
Spec started
(node:34486) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, tutorial-overlay)
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

  Outer describe block name

    Inner describe block name
      ✗ should show show the welcome overlay
        - Failed: this.testDocument.save is not a function
```